# How to cumulate/preserve old frames using the Animation package?

Tags: r, animation

The code below plots 10 dots on the x-axis, one at a time. At any one point in time, the animation displays only one dot. I am looking to end up with a plot with all 10 dots. I would like the second dot to be added to the plot showing the first dot; the third to be added to the plot showing the first two dots, etc. I looked at the documentation for saveGIF for a parameter that would somehow cumulate the frames, but could not find a relevant parameter there. It looks like it should be possible. Yihui Xie, the creator of the animation package, did exactly that in the top right plot of this example https://yihui.org/animation/example/buffon-needle/

```
library(animation)
    
saveGIF({
   for (i in 1:10) {
       x <- rnorm(1,0,1)
       plot(x,0,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(-1,1))
                   } 
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the 10 numbers in advance, and plot them incrementally, e.g.,

```r
library(animation)

saveGIF({
  n <- 10
  x <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    plot(head(x, i), 0, xlim = c(1, n), ylim = c(-1, 1))
  }
})
```

Comment: This is super helpful. The head(x,i) piece was the one I was missing. Please note that I had to replace the 0 in the plot line with rep.int(0,i) to make the lengths of x and y the same and had to set xlim=c(-3,3) so as to see all points, but these are minor details. Your answer solved the main conceptual problem I was having. Thank you, Yihui.